# How to force an MS Word download to a particular location

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I used the code below to download an MS Word file to a default download folder. But I need the document to be downloaded to a specific location. How can I do this?

**Code:**

```
<cfcontent type="application/msword">
<cfheader name="content-Disposition" value="attachment;filename=Simple_run.doc">
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this code to save an MS Word document to particular location.

I made noticeEmail content as document. Happy coding.

```
<cfsavecontent variable="whatever">
    <cfinclude template="noticeEmail.cfm">
</cfsavecontent>   
<cffile action="WRITE" file="#WordFilePath#.doc" output="#whatever#">
```

Comment: It doesn't sound like  he's running CFML on the client machine here

Comment: sorry i cant understand,please explain

Answer (score 8):

You can only dispatch the file to the client. It is the user agent's job to decide how to deal with the file that is being sent. Some browsers will prompt the user for location, others will default to a download directory. This cannot be dictated by the server.

Answer (score 6):

You can't. The destination is controlled by browser and system preferences, not the webpage. You can set the file name but that's all. That's not a bug or oversight either, it's deliberate to prevent websites from tricking users into overwriting system files.

Mind you, if you control the client machine as well (like in an intranet) you have a few more options. The simplest is to use a custom mime type and then write a small program to handle the actual filesystem copy to your target folder.

Comment: You can set the name of the file you're *sending*, just as you can control pretty much all aspects of what you're sending, but when it comes to saving the file, the user decides the filename too (although the default implementation of most browsers would be to pre-populate this with the name as sent from the server). A minor difference, perhaps, but it seems to me that the distinction between what is being sent, and how it's handled at the receiver end is key in this entire question.